# Merging cells if border

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with merging cells.
In my excel file I have a lot of data whitch is OCR.
So OCR file looks like this:

[image]

But I like to be this:

[image]

Do You have any idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Read this article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Merge-and-unmerge-cells-in-Excel-for-Mac-f4ef88e4-5a79-402b-bbfa-ed7ddaddba4b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US see if it helps

Comment: Hi,It is working ok but I have 12000 lines. So if I will do that manuly it will be long long time.

Comment: Do You know some procedure in VBA to finde borderd cells or group of bordered cells?

Comment: Hi as far as I know, FINDING the cell value rather than the bordered cell might be the one you needed.

Comment: No it will not work. How would You know if the vale is for name4 or name1 ect... Borders are telling you that, it is one block. By the way some blocks are two, three or four lines long...